# TypeError inflection.js

Tags: node.js

I built a simple Node project and trying to start it, but i'm getting this error when running **node src/server.js**:

```
cassio@cassio-Aspire-A315-53:~/Projects/Coffee$ node src/server.js
```

/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/inflection/lib/inflection.js:594
var ignore = ( inflector.indexOf( skip, str.toLowerCase()) > -1 );
^

TypeError: str.toLowerCase is not a function
at Object._apply_rules (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/inflection/lib/inflection.js:594:53)
at Object.pluralize (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/inflection/lib/inflection.js:670:24)
at Object.pluralize (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:113:21)
at Function.init (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/sequelize/lib/model.js:936:23)
at Sequelize.define (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:440:11)
at module.exports (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/src/app/models/user.js:2:26)
at /home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/src/app/models/index.js:24:54
at Array.forEach ()
at Object. (/home/cassio/Projects/Coffee/src/app/models/index.js:23:4)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
cassio@cassio-Aspire-A315-53:~/Projects/Coffee$

EDIT: The code https://github.com/cassioaalmeida/Testrepo

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: https://github.com/cassioaalmeida/Testrepo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 'src/app/models/user.js', the schema name is wrongly defined. It should be string not array. Try this:

```js
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const user = sequelize.define("user", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password_hash: DataTypes.STRING,
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check whether the function is defined or not